# byte-compile and lexical-binding

Tags: byte-compilation, lexical-scoping, lexical-binding

Could someone in the know please help me understand what's going on here:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let* ((a 0))
  (let* ((a 1))
    (funcall (byte-compile (lambda () a)))))
;;=> 0
```

wat? Not only that, but with `lexical-binding` off this actually returns `1`. I even Edebug stepped the `byte-compile` and it definitely sees closure with `a` correctly shadowed and holding `1`. Do I misunderstand scoping rules here or how `byte-compile` works?

PS: or is that an artifact of `eval-last-sexp` somehow? Because I just tried this and it worked as I expected:

```
(lexical-let* ((a 0))
  (lexical-let* ((a 1))
    (funcall (byte-compile (lambda () a)))))
```

---

**EDIT** Yet another unexpected quirk that maybe related.

Let's define a function that checks if `lexical-binding` is enabled. Then define a macro that inserts that check before doing whatever.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun test-for-lexical-binding ()
  (unless lexical-binding
    (error "lexical binding disabled!")))

(defmacro foo-macro ()
  `(progn
     (test-for-lexical-binding)
     42))
```

Let's now use that macro in `foo.el`.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(foo-macro)
```

You can `byte-compile-file` fine, but the moment you load the byte-code the check fails:

```
(byte-compile-file "foo.el" 'load)
;;=> lexical binding disabled!
```

You can easily verify with `(eval-when-compile lexical-binding)` that `lexical-binding` is indeed set when you compile, but `nil` when the code actually runs.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Note that `lexical-let` uses dynamic binding (it's a trick with renaming things behind the scenes), so it's expected that it would produce the same result as the "with lexical-binding off" result.

Comment: @phils yeah, I looked under the hood almost right away. I get the feeling its pre "native" lexical-binding trick that by the looks of its expansion must be quite wasteful but does the trick.  I solved my immediate problem by also passing let-bindings to lambda as arguments but that's just meh. I've seen people programmatically generate a temp-file with `lexical-binding` local prop-line and compile the file. I guess I'm beginning to understand why

Comment: Yes, `lexical-let` dates back 25 years at minimum. `lexical-binding` was only introduced in Emacs 24.

Comment: I think your `test-for-lexical-binding` error is due to the fix for [Bug#12938](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12938).

Answer (score 1):

The `lexical-binding` is a setting that by-and-large operates at compile-time and not at run-time (more specifically, it applies to code that's being *manipulated* rather than code that's being *executed*).  So at run-time, better not pay too much attention to it (its value will depend on the buffer that happens to be current when the code is executed) unless you're *manipulating* code (in which case you will want to consult `lexical-binding` to determine how that code should be handled).

You can easily fix your test by moving it to macro-expansion-time: macros can consult `lexical-binding` in order to know whether the code they emit will be interpreted in the lexbind version of Elisp or in the dynbind version of Elisp.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29:

The problem is in `byte-compile--reify-function` within `byte-compile`.

In an edebug session `byte-compile--reify-function` transforms
`'(closure ((a . 1) (a . 0) t) nil a)`
into
`(lambda nil (let ((a (quote 1)) (a (quote 0))) a))`
which is wrong.

`(funcall '(closure ((a . 1) (a . 0) t) nil a))`
gives 1 which shows that the lexical environment is looked up in the sense of `assoc`, i.e., the first match wins.

Opposed to that, the last binding for `a` is relevant in the `let`-form.

---

Since it is `let` and not `let*` a simple fix would be to reverse the order of the bindings in the `let`-form.
Note that such a simple fix works for your case with constant expressions but not for the general case where the expressions are evaluated themselves.
The evaluation order of the expressions is changed by the fix which can be disastrous.

The original version of `byte-compile--reify-function` is as follows.

```el
(defun byte-compile--reify-function (fun)
  "Return an expression which will evaluate to a function value FUN.
FUN should be either a `lambda' value or a `closure' value."
  (pcase-let* (((or (and `(lambda ,args . ,body) (let env nil))
                    `(closure ,env ,args . ,body))
                fun)
               (preamble nil)
               (renv ()))
    ;; Split docstring and `interactive' form from body.
    (when (stringp (car body))
      (push (pop body) preamble))
    (when (eq (car-safe (car body)) 'interactive)
      (push (pop body) preamble))
    ;; Turn the function's closed vars (if any) into local let bindings.
    (dolist (binding env)
      (cond
       ((consp binding)
        ;; We check shadowing by the args, so that the `let' can be moved
        ;; within the lambda, which can then be unfolded.  FIXME: Some of those
        ;; bindings might be unused in `body'.
        (unless (memq (car binding) args) ;Shadowed.
          (push `(,(car binding) ',(cdr binding)) renv)))
       ((eq binding t))
       (t (push `(defvar ,binding) body))))
    (if (null renv)
        `(lambda ,args ,@preamble ,@body)
      `(lambda ,args ,@preamble (let ,(nreverse renv) ,@body)))))
```

We fix it by removing the last `nreverse`:

```el
(defun byte-compile--reify-function (fun)
  "Return an expression which will evaluate to a function value FUN.
FUN should be either a `lambda' value or a `closure' value."
  (pcase-let* (((or (and `(lambda ,args . ,body) (let env nil))
                    `(closure ,env ,args . ,body))
                fun)
               (preamble nil)
               (renv ()))
    ;; Split docstring and `interactive' form from body.
    (when (stringp (car body))
      (push (pop body) preamble))
    (when (eq (car-safe (car body)) 'interactive)
      (push (pop body) preamble))
    ;; Turn the function's closed vars (if any) into local let bindings.
    (dolist (binding env)
      (cond
       ((consp binding)
        ;; We check shadowing by the args, so that the `let' can be moved
        ;; within the lambda, which can then be unfolded.  FIXME: Some of those
        ;; bindings might be unused in `body'.
        (unless (memq (car binding) args) ;Shadowed.
          (push `(,(car binding) ',(cdr binding)) renv)))
       ((eq binding t))
       (t (push `(defvar ,binding) body))))
    (if (null renv)
        `(lambda ,args ,@preamble ,@body)
      `(lambda ,args ,@preamble (let ,renv ,@body)))))
```

You can evaluate the last `defun` in the `*scratch*` buffer. Afterwards `eval-last-sexp` of your first elisp snippet gives 1, as expected.